# Photoshop, no infinit move with the spacebar?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I user the spacebar to move in my document, when i zoom i can use spacebar to move to the infinit but when i unzoom, the document stay at center and i can't go on the left side at infinit.

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behaviour. In the default display mode, your canvas stays in the center of the screen when you are zoomed out enough for the entire canvas to be visible.

To enable panning at any zoom you can enable full-screen mode (and cycle through all the display modes) by pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> key.

Since Photoshop CC-2014 there is now a preference to enable this behaviour in the default display mode (**Preferences → Interface → Overscroll**). I believe there is an Adobe plugin to enable this pre CC but I can't find a link right now.